# Windows Media Foundation -- IMFActivate::ActivateObject() RPC Error?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, webcam, ms-media-foundation

I've had this problem for a few days now. I would like to interface with a web cam using Windows Media Foundation classes, but for whatever reason, any time I call

```
IMFActivate::ActivateObject()
```

To open up a capture source, it yields a 0x800706d9 Error:

> 0x800706d9 : There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.  HRESULT

I am using Windows 10 LTSB, and have used 2 different machines with different web cams, all yielding the same result. I have even used an off-the-shelf library from here (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/559437/Capturing-Video-from-Web-camera-on-Windows-and-by) that is supposed to work, but I get the same problem at the same function.

Here is the particular line in that library:

```
hr = pActivate->ActivateObject(
        __uuidof(IMFMediaSource),
        (void**)&pSource
        );
```

It is a cryptic problem that I can't seem to solve. Has anyone dealt with this before?

Thanks

Comment: To anyone who wants to know how to fix this problem if you ever run into it yourselves (it seems so rare I doubt it would happen), see the following link:

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-the-windows-10-anniversary-edition-webcam-bug/

Comment: Frame server feature you disabled exhibited a number of issues when originally introduced. Microsoft improved things greatly in the course of a few moths. I am not sure how your LTSB version is late against current version, but presumably you are seeing one of those frame server related issues.

Comment: I suspect the fix might be bundled as a "feature update", from which the LTSB updates are excluded. I've included a registry patch in my installer for this LTSB version (or other 14393 builds).

Comment: Use this SDK tool to troubleshoot: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff685370(v=vs.85).aspx It'll probably tell you the reason for that error.